# Adding numbers stored in variables in windows batch script

Tags: windows, scripting, batch

I have a loop in a batch script and I would like to do some arithmetics with the loop counter. I found out how to evaluate expressions, how to add numbers here: [Evaluating expressions in windows batch script](https://serverfault.com/questions/60039/evaluating-expressions-in-windows-batch-script)

How do I do the same but with variables?

For example:

```
set x = 100
for /L %%i in (1,1,5) do (
    set Result=0
    set /a Result = %%i+%%x
    echo %Result%
)
```

As output I would expect

101
102
103
104
105

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You really should move away from Batch files.

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set x=100
set result=0

for /L %%i in (1,1,5) do (

  set /A result=!x! + %%i

  echo !result!
)

endlocal
```

Comment: Yeah.  Powershell == good.

Comment: But batch files == challenge. And challenges are fun :)

Answer (score 1):

You are resetting Result to zero at each step. Move that before the loop. Also, try `help set` at the `cmd` prompt for more information on all this. Especially look at the section on delayed environment variable expansion.

Comment: Although yes, it was a glaring error on his part, the problem still can't be solved without using *delayed expansion*

Comment: That's why I included the sentence that begins "Especially...".